# Display pdf file downloaded from database in an embed tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, embed

We are trying to fetch pdf files from database in byte array format. when user clicks on display button it should be displayed in an embed tag which appears on top of screen. But when we convert the byte array to base64string it doesn't apear in embed file.

```
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.File)
<a href="#" onclick="OpenPDF();">Display</a>
</td>
```

When user press Display button, OpenPDF script will open:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function OpenPDF() {

                document.getElementById("pdfBack").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("pdfDialog").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("pdfFile").setAttribute("src", "data:application/pdf;base64," + @Convert.ToBase64String(item.File));
            }
        </script>
```

And this is the embed tag:

```
<embed id="pdfFile" type="application/pdf" src="" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

It doesn't work! embed tag will open after pressing button, but there is no pdf file inside the mebed.

[image: This is our page]

[image: The embed file apear without pdf file]

Please help us how should we handle this problem

Answer (score 0):

To display a PDF *properly* directly on the browser you need to use some kind of PDF viewer ie google docs or you can use libraries like PDF.js.

1. Using google doc ->

```
<iframe src=" http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://path.com/to/your/pdf.pdf&embedded=true"  ></iframe>
```

For this to work you need to host your PDF's somewhere online.

2. You can also use PDF.js http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/
   check examples to make it work for you.

To make embed solution work you will need to host your file some where already and provide that path in your src.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function OpenPDF() {

                document.getElementById("pdfBack").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("pdfDialog").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("pdfFile").setAttribute("src", "http://yourwebsite.com/" + fileName );
            }
        </script>

<embed src="" width="500" height="375" 
 type="application/pdf">
```

I would suggest to use PDF.js if hosting the file is a problem.

Also chrome on android doesn't support embeds with PDF files so if you are expecting android users use PDF.js or google docs.